# CPanel Backup via Google Drive API - 403 Errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, cpanel

We are backing up CPanel to our Google Drive account as a secondary backup. However the Google Drive API is reporting 403 errors when trying to do this.

We are able to transfer the first weeks set of backups and then in the following week of the month it does a few and then fails.

I assume we are hitting some sort of quota but I cannot see where I can remove this quota limit.

Happy to pay to increase quota just don't know where it is being blocked.

I have reviewed Google Cloud Console and can see the errors - https://i.imgur.com/TR6n6m9.png

Any ideas would be great.